# Firebase version update issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to update my firebase id & firebase messaging version but it gives me error

```
   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0"
   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2"
   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0"

   implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0"
   implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
   implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0"
```

> Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@[16.0.0], but fire
>   base-iid version was 19.0.0.

**Also giving following errors:**

> The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
>   ifact with the issue.
>   -- Project 'mifosng' depends on project 'debugCompileClasspath' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytic
>   s@17.0.0
>   -- Project 'mifosng' depends on project 'debugCompileClasspath' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@17.
>   0.0
>   -- Project 'mifosng' depends on project 'debugCompileClasspath' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messagin
>   g@17.0.0

Comment: migrate to androidx dependency this will go away.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Did you try any of the answers below?

Answer (score 1):

**This happened to me before, You need to add/enable AndroidX in your project**

Do not forget to add these in your **Project properties:**

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
```

And

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

in dependencies of the top level build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2"
```

As it is a transitive dependency used in `firebase-messaging` which means `firebase-messaging` already uses it. So just remove `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2"` from your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I have removed implementation `"com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2"` and now getting following error   `Gradle sync failed: The library com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 19.0.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies`